# Need to sleep in smalltalk for step animation

Tags: sleep, smalltalk, squeak

In smalltalk (squeak environment) i am trying to animate some objects, like make blinking during some other process. But it only works when all other processes are over, so i guess there is not enough time for that (is it?).

I tried "(delay forMilliseconds:500) wait" at some points, but it still did't work, like if delay itself blocks program running.

So how can i sleep instead?

Answer (score 4):

The delay actually blocks. That's its responsibility: “halt” the current process for the specified amount of time.

There are some ideas to overcome that.

#### Morphic Stepping

You can make a Morph receive the `#step` message in a defined interval:

```
YourMorph>>step
   "Assuming that myState is an instance variable with accessors"

   self color: (self myState ifTrue: [Color blue] ifFalse: [Color red]).
   self myState: self myState not
```

The frequency of `#step` being called is dependent on the `#stepTime`:

```
YourMorph>>stepTime

    "Call #step every quarter second"
    ^ 250 "ms"
```

Also, you can toggle whether your Morph receives `#step` at all with `#startStepping` and `#stopStepping`.

This should allow a quite nice blinking animation

#### Morphic Alarms

If you need infrequent messages sent to your asynchronously, you can use alarms.

That is, you schedule a message to be sent after a specific amount of time (`#addAlarm:after:`) or at a specific point in time (`#addAlarm:at:`).

Assume that your morph wants to get sent the `#toggleAThing` message after 500 milliseconds, you can do

```
yourMorph addAlarm: #toggleAThing after: 500 "ms".
```

Beware that this is a one-shot. It gets only sent once. For periodic messages, stepping is better.

#### Manual sleeping (beware)

You can actually use delays to induce “later” messages. For that you would enclose the delay in a block and make a new process.

Suppose you want the `#toggleAThing` message being sent to your object after 350 milliseconds, you could do the following:

```
[(Delay forMilliseconds: 350) wait.
 yourObject toggleAThing.
] fork.
"Not blocking, continue doing things"
```

Note that you should read a bit about scheduling in Squeak (for example by reading the implementation of the `Process` class) before trying that. A better version of this is available as “Future sends”

#### Future Sends

This is the most general way to receive or send an asynchronous message. You simply specify the time difference until the message is sent and *then* send it:

```
(yourObject future: 350 "ms") toggleAThing
```

Comment: Tobias, thank you. I don't understand almost a thing :) Where do you specify the interval? Or what is myState?

Comment: Oh, that explains it:) anyway, unfortunately that doesn't answer my question. I did use stepTime and startStepping. But again, the blinking only starts working when the algorithm stops. Like if there are no timer interrupts to do the "step" while everything else runs on.

Comment: Then please add more information to your question, for example some more code.

Comment: maybe you mean:    self color: (self myState ifTrue: [Color blue] ifFalse: [Color red]).

Answer (score 0):

At a certain point, you might need to do a

`World doOneCycle`

to get the redraw.